# Series connection of digital PT1 filters

Tags: filters, discrete-signals, signal-analysis

I was trying design $N^{th}$ order filter, I was suggested a series connection of low-pass PT1 filter. Basically, the filter coefficients are like this:

$$a_i = \dbinom{n}{i} T^{i}$$

This works for $N^{th}$ order, while $a_1, a_2, a_3....a_n$ being the filter coefficient.

I don't know how this works, in theory. I tried searching, but could not come up with anything. if anyone has any idea about this. I want to know how this works.

Comment: What is $T$? Is $N=n$ in your equations?

Comment: $T$ is filter time constant, $T=\frac{1}{2*\pi *fc}$ andand sorry $N=n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have mentioned where you got that formula from. But anyway, I'll try to reconstruct it.

A first order discrete-time low pass filter has the following transfer function:

$$H(z)=\frac{1+c}{1+cz^{-1}},\qquad -1<c<0\tag{1}$$

where the constant $c$ determines the cut-off frequency. If you cascade $N$ of these filters, the total transfer function is

$$H_N(z)=\prod_{k=1}^NH(z)=\frac{(1+c)^N}{(1+cz^{-1})^N}\tag{2}$$

Using the [Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) this can be written as

$$H_N(z)=\frac{(1+c)^N}{\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^N\dbinom{N}{k}c^kz^{-k}}=\frac{(1+c)^N}{\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^Na_kz^{-k}}\tag{3}$$

with denominator coefficients

$$a_k=\dbinom{N}{k}c^k\tag{4}$$

Note that the numerator $(1+c)^N$ is just there to make sure that the scaling is correct, i.e., that the transfer function equals $1$ at $z=1$ (DC).

---

Following [MBaz's suggestion](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/34242/series-connection-of-digital-pt1-filters/34250?noredirect=1#comment64994_34250), I add the relationship between the constant $c$ in $(1)$ and the filter's $3\,\text{dB}$ cut-off frequency $\omega_c$. For this we have to solve

$$|H(e^{j\omega_c})|^2=\frac12|H(1)|^2=\frac12\tag{5}$$

From $(1)$ we get

$$\frac{(1+c)^2}{1+2c\cdot \cos(\omega_c)+c^2}=\frac12\tag{6}$$

from which we obtain after some elementary algebra

$$c=\cos(\omega_c)-2+\sqrt{\cos^2(\omega_c)-4\cos(\omega_c)+3}\tag{7}$$

Comment: Is there any paper or book i can cite this?

Comment: @Aashu10: I don't know, it's just a basic application of the binomial theorem, nothing special.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had actually derived in another domain, I wanted to read more about these, that's the reason i was asking  for a source. If you know anything about where i can read more about them to understand more. That'd be helpful

Comment: @Aashu10: OK, but what I wrote in my answer is really everything there is to it. Is it clear?

Comment: @MattL. Nice analysis; the only thing I would add is how to calculate $c$ to obtain a specified cutoff frequency $f_c$.

Comment: @MBaz: OK, edited.

Comment: @MattL. I may be missing something but that doesn't look right. The equation you gave for $c$ is periodic, which means several different $c$'s are associated with the same $f_c$. For instance, I get $c=-1$ for any integer $f_c>0$.

Comment: @MBaz: Of course it's periodic, because we're dealing with a discrete-time system. The interval for $\omega_c$ we're looking at is $0<\omega_c<\pi$. E.g., if you choose $\omega_c=\pi/2$, you get $c=-2+\sqrt{3}=-0.27$. Check it again, I might miss a typo, but I think it's correct.

Comment: @MattL. I see -- I misinterpreted the units of $\omega_c$ as radians per second. It makes sense now.